# jboss server startup taking too much time

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, jboss6.x

I am using jboss 6.2 server  it is taking 20 mins for startup. i tried with different versions of jboss and different IDEs still i am getting same issue. below are some of the config details
RAM 16gb,Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -MM:MaxPermSize=256m.please help me with this issue , thanks in advance

Comment: any suggestions??

Comment: dont open duplicate threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137053/jboss-6-x-server-taking-long-time-to-start

Answer (score 0):

The case seems interesting but we would need more information.
i.e. server.log and configuration files.

On your specific case:

1. Try to deploy using a different method:
   Deployments folder and deploy via CLI or console.
2. Verify is the deployment directory is clean, if it's not, clean it, and try again.